# How do I get an overview of recent activity for a GitHub repository?

Tags: github, statistics

For many GitHub repositories, there is a lot of activity going on per day. It would be nice to have an overview of all recent activity going on in the GitHub repository. Is there such a feature available?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GitHub's **Pulse** feature allows you to find an overview of all recent activity in a repository (here's their [post announcing the feature](https://github.com/blog/1476-get-up-to-speed-with-pulse)). This would include:

- New/Closed Pull requests and Issues
- Number of authors who made commits during the period specified
- Number of commits made
- Number of files changed
- Number of lines added and removed
- List of top contributors to the repository

It is possible to select the desired amount of time you wish to see. Available options are 24 hours before, 3 days before, 1 week before *(default)* and 1 month before. You can access it using the left-most heartbeat icon of any repository. It is also possible to see statistics up to 1 year before by manipulating the URL and changing the time factor to "yearly" (i.e. if you are in the month view, change "monthly" to "yearly").

[image: Location of icon]

Comment: I see stats for 1 week if I try `yearly`.

Comment: Me too. But if you click on "Contributors" in the column on the left, then the top graph shows you the overall activity (commits) over the lifetime of the project.  Helpful for figuring out whether a low-activity project is dead or still maintained.